# Will Lightning Web Components be open sourced or available for external apps?

Tags: lightning-web-components

We prefer to use back-end APIs to connect to salesforce and write our own applications in .net and java. Will the Lightning Web Components be available for this use case?

Answer (score 6):

Our goal is to fully open source lightning web components and all its related packages in a similar fashion as Vue, react, ember, etc.

That means that you will able to use your components and modules not only at Salesforce but anywhere else and push them to whatever stack of your choice, just like any other framework or project. We design it with that goal from the very beginning.

Moreover as part of the Web Component paradigm you will be able to trivially embed your components and make them interoperate with any other framework and stack.

As for when, we want to make sure we have the resources and focus to be able to do it right so give us a couple of months.

Will keep you all posted! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Lightning Out" use case : not yet covered by Lightning Web Components, bu on the roadmap

Comment: We target to have lighting out officially supported (safe harbor) next release, however if you look at my other answer, we want to  go beyond just lightning out and make full use of the new lightning components paradigm so you will be to trivially interoperate and share them anywhere